# how to resize and position Drawables inside a LayerDrawable in Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, drawable, layer

I have a LayerDrawable, which should display 5 Bitmaps. 1 background and 4 Icons (which can be different for every LayerDrawable) like a Grid. Unfortunately these Icons don't have the same width than height. My Problem is to resize them, while keeping their ratio and place them inside their Position (1-4 Icons, 5 background):

```
==================
|      |  |      |
|   1  |  |   2  |
|------.5 .------|
|------.  .------|
|   3  |  |   4  |
|      |  |      |
==================
```

If I resize these Bitmaps, give them `Gravity.CENTER` they won't fit anymore inside the Bounds of the Background Rectangle. If I leave `Gravity.CENTER` they seem to get rescaled as soon as I call `layerDrawable.setLayerInset(numlayer, left, top, right, bottom)`.
What is the right way to do it? How can I keep their ratio while placing them correctly?
What I also couldn't understand so far is why getIntrinsicWidth/Height from BitmapDrawable is returning something else (smaller) than getWidth/Height from original Bitmap.
What I tried:
1. Getting them from XML, putting a 'dummy-drawable' inside and replace it with result described above. 
2. Create LayerDrawable inside my Program passing all drawables inside. It seems that setLayerInset has no affect, or I only see the Background (which was Element 0 inside my Drawable Array)
3. Extending LayerDrawable and try to keep track on anything myself without reasonable results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BitmapDrawable`, dy default, fills its bounds with the given `Bitmap`. If you start using `Gravity`, the `Bitmap` will be position according to the given `Gravity`. I suppose in your case, the best choice is to create your own `Drawable`.

Concerning the getIntrinsic[Height|Width] methods, they return the actual size of your underlying `Bitmap` which may be different if the system resized it it while loading it (an hdpi image loaded on an mdpi screen for instance).